# ggplot2 - facetting some variables while keeping others on the same plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I'd like to know the best way to plot some variables on separate different plots, while keeping others on the same plot.

For the example below, I'd like to have `Temperature_sensor_1` and `Temperature_sensor_1` on the same plot (each sensor as a different line) whereas the other variables plotted individually.

I can do it by creating a variable in which both temperature measurements are combined and then use the line color aesthetic to split into each sensor type.

```
library(tidyverse)

df_results <- data.frame(
  Time_point =seq(0, 19, by=1),
  Alitude=rnorm(20, mean=50, sd=2),
  Temperature_sensor_1=rnorm(20, mean=40, sd=2),
  Temperature_sensor_2=rnorm(20, mean=45, sd=2),
  Pressure=rnorm(20, mean=20, sd=2)
)

df_results<-df_results%>%
  pivot_longer(-Time_point,names_to = "Measurement")

#create new variables
df_results<-df_results%>%
  mutate(Measurement_type = if_else(grepl("^T",Measurement),"Temperature",Measurement))%>%
  mutate(Sensor_ID = if_else(grepl("Temp",Measurement_type),Measurement,"NA"))

ggplot(df_results, aes(x=Time_point, y=value))+
  geom_line(aes(colour = Sensor_ID), size=1)+  
  facet_wrap(~Measurement_type,scales = "fixed")
```

Creating the new variables doesn't feel right, and I'd like to avoid the 'NA's. Is there a better way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, you have `Measurement_type` and you have `Sensor_ID`.  To avoid the NAs, what about just understanding that those poor old Altitude and Pressure sensors need IDs too!  If there's only 1 sensor, it's "Sensor 1".  If there are two sensors, you have a "Sensor 1" and a "Sensor 2".  In other words, try changing your `# create new variables` section to this:

```
df_results<-df_results%>%
  mutate(Measurement_type = if_else(grepl("^T",Measurement),"Temperature",Measurement)) %>%
  mutate(Sensor_ID = if_else(grepl("sensor_2",Measurement),"Sensor 2","Sensor 1"))
```

Running your same plot code then produces this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you could create a new column with `mutate` and `case_when` and use this to make the facet.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_results <- data.frame(
  Time_point =seq(0, 19, by=1),
  Alitude=rnorm(20, mean=50, sd=2),
  Temperature_sensor_1=rnorm(20, mean=40, sd=2),
  Temperature_sensor_2=rnorm(20, mean=45, sd=2),
  Pressure=rnorm(20, mean=20, sd=2)
)

df_results<-df_results%>%
  pivot_longer(-Time_point,names_to = "Measurement")

df_results <- df_results %>% 
  mutate(newVar = case_when(
    Measurement %in% c('Temperature_sensor_1', 'Temperature_sensor_2') ~ 'Temperatures',
    Measurement == 'Alitude' ~ 'Altitude',
    Measurement == 'Pressure' ~ 'Pressure'
  ))

ggplot(df_results, aes(x=Time_point, y=value))+
  geom_line(aes(colour = Measurement), size=1)+  
  facet_wrap(~newVar,scales = "fixed")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>